# How to use apply attribute on tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I tried to change all NaN elements in column b to 1 if column a is not NaN in the same row. eg: a==1 b==NaN ,change b to 1. Here is my code.

```
raw_data['b'] = ((raw_data['a'],raw_data['b']).apply(condition))

def condition(a,b):
if a != None and b == None:
    return 1
```

And I got an AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'apply'. What other methods I can use in this situation?

Comment: If it can work with Numpy, fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First create boolean mask by chained conditions with `&` with functions [`isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isnull.html) and [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html).

Then is more possible solutions for add `1` - with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
mask = raw_data['a'].notnull() & raw_data['b'].isnull()
```

```
raw_data['b'] = raw_data['b'].mask(mask, 1)
```

Or:

```
raw_data.loc[mask, 'b'] = 1
```

Or:

```
raw_data['b'] = np.where(mask, 1,raw_data['b'])
```

Sample:

```
raw_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1,np.nan, np.nan],
    'b': [np.nan, np.nan,2]
})
print (raw_data)
     a    b
0  1.0  NaN
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  2.0

mask = raw_data['a'].notnull() & raw_data['b'].isnull()

print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

raw_data.loc[mask, 'b'] = 1

print (raw_data)
     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  2.0
```

EDIT:

If want use custom function (really slow if more data) need [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for processing by rows:

```
def condition(x):
    if pd.notnull(x.a) and pd.isnull(x.b):
        return 1
    else:
        return x.b

raw_data['b'] = raw_data.apply(condition, axis=1)

print (raw_data)
     a    b
0  1.0  1.0
1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  2.0
```